# ie7 shows the url below each link

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, boilerplate

On a web page I am developing, I noticeed that my navigation bar (only in IE7) shows the anchor text and the complete and ugly URL below, I don´t want this text to be shown, how can I hide It? Why is this happening?

Excuse me, this is the html code:

```
<div id="proa1">
    <h1 style="font-size: 2.6em; margin-left: 12%; line-height:1em; color:#7acd31">Proyectos</h1>
    <h2 style="margin-left: 12%">
        <a href="direcciones.html" title="Direcciones de obra realizadas por LMC arquitectura">Direcciones de obra</a>
    </h2>
    <h2 style="margin-left: 12%">
        <a href="gestion-tecnica.html" title="Gestión Técnica realizada por LMC arquitectura">Gestión Técnica</a>
    </h2>
</div>
```

And I have just noticed it is related to boilerplate.css

and I can tell you it is solved.

This was an HTML file written in a new fluid grid dreamweaver document. This document is linked to boilerplate.css (unknown for me)

At the end of this file there is a section for printing and there were these atributes. After commenting this lines it can be seen ok in a simulator of IE7

```
@media print {
 * { background: transparent !important; color: black !important; text-shadow: none !important; filter:none !important; -ms-filter: none !important; } /* La impresión en negro es más rápida: h5bp.com/s */
/*  a, a:visited { text-decoration: underline; }
a[href]:after { content: " (" attr(href) ")"; }
abbr[title]:after { content: " (" attr(title) ")"; }
.ir a:after, a[href^="javascript:"]:after, a[href^="#"]:after { content: ""; }  /* No mostrar para imágenes ni para código javascript/vínculos internos */
 pre, blockquote { border: 1px solid #999; page-break-inside: avoid; }
thead { display: table-header-group; } /* h5bp.com/t */
tr, img { page-break-inside: avoid; }
img { max-width: 100% !important; }
@page { margin: 0.5cm; }
p, h2, h3 { orphans: 3; widows: 3; }
h2, h3 { page-break-after: avoid; }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you edited your question and added the HTML of an anchor tag (a link) that is showing this behaviour.

Comment: We really need to see some code, or ideally the page you're having the problem with. There isn't enough information here to be able to help you.

Comment: *"if I paste the code, dissapears"* when you edit your question, there is a big yellow box on the right side, titled "How to format", which says *"indent code by 4 spaces"*. Not that difficult, is it?

Comment: Not that difficult, indeed. Thanks Mr. Kling

Answer (score 0):

You could i.e. change the href attr and take the link with javascript...

```
<script>
    $("a").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var href = $this.attr("href");
        if (typeof href != 'undefined' && href) {
            $this.attr("href", "something else..");
            $this.data("alt-href", href);
        }
    });
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var alt = $this.data("alt-href");
        if (typeof alt != 'undefined' && alt) {
            window.location = alt;
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    })
</script>
```

however, why should someone do this?

Comment: This doesn't take into account the target attribute, people middle-mouse-clicking the link, opening via the context menu, etc. It's really not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you, but I believe this can be fixed someway with html-css only. But I don't know how and I don't have any IE7 to check it either :(